# How to embedded user credentials on iOS for ArcGIS runtime SDK to access portal?

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I try to build a native iOS access to access the ArcGIS webmap via our enterprise portal server. The webmap is secured and need to be authenticate. On the browser, it need to type the user id and password in order to access it. How can I embedded the user id and password? I am using ArcGIS runtime for iOS to access the map.

let map = AGSMap(url: url)

mapView.map = map
mapView.touchDelegate = self
mapView.setViewpoint(AGSViewpoint(latitude: 50.69295, longitude: -63.987547, scale: 2027.977411))

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We'll answer your question on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-ios-questions/embedded-user-user-credentials-in-the-app-without/m-p/1105397#M7141).